# Graphical front-end for references in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, reference, bibtex

is there any graphical plugin/front-end for eclipse to handle/search for references
like in Mendeley or Endnote. I know that the texClipse plugin comes with a bibtex editor but it takes quite a while to put all references together by hand.

Regards,
syrvn

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I don't know about any such plug-in.

Maybe Mendeley can export selected publications into a bib file that can be used with Texlipse (AFAIK Zotero, the manager I use can do this).